# Power BI report, shared capacity & Pro licence in Azure

Tags: azure, powerbi, licensing, powerbi-embedded

We have enabled Power BI Embedded service in Azure

We have created Power BI reports using Pro Licence user's workspace & assigned this workspace in Azure Power BI embedded resource.

Now we need to share these reports to users (> 500) within organization who has Office 365 accounts.

When these users tries to see we are getting error
"This content is only available to users with a Power BI Pro license. Upgrade today to get access to collaborate with others and distribute content."

[image]

This was working fine when we have done POC with client and now while deploying application in client's UAT environment, we suddenly started getting this error.

What is solution/workaround (Responsive too) for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a license issue as you might be sharing pro-user content to non pro users.

Can you please try with power bi embedded to share the reports.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/power-bi-embedded/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers

Thanks.